# Upload an audio file on node.js, add audio visualisation (with three.js) and save the new file to a video file

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, tone.js

I would like to upload an audio file to a node server, and create an animation with three js (audio visualization) and make the new file a video file.

(an exemple of audio visualisation : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7iHvXq4hEE)

I found some solutions to make that happen on the client-side with Tone.js or three.js, then record the audio visualization from the browser in "real-time", and send it back to the server,

like this one : https://gracexu94.github.io/FinalProject/

but this is happening in "real time" and I would like here to be able to upload audio of 40minutes without having to wait this amount of time before to get the file back,,,

Any ideas for this process ?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? record it, not in real time?